# What is the right Java-way to create objects dynamically?

Tags: java

Let's assume I have a package `foo` with few classes; `Foo1, Foo2, Foo3`. All of them implements `IFoo` which has one method. Now, I have another class, `Baz` which make use of all those classes. Basically `baz` need to call the method of every `IFoo` class.

Note:

- They can be reused. Meaning, we only need to create them once.
- I might want to add `Foo4` someday.

Now, what I was able to think of is creating a singleton, `FooSingleton` which encapsulate all those classes and load them by:

1. reading a `foo.xml` file.
2. reflection
3. just write `new Foo1();`, `new Foo2();` etc, inside the init function of the singleton.

So I wanted to know what's the preferable way (Maybe there's another neat way I haven't think of)

By the way, I've encountered with [Spring Dependency Injection](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_dependency_injection.htm) but that looked to me a little bit of an overhead.

Comment: I would just called `new Foo1()` when you need to `Foo1`, unless there is a reason to make it more complicated whihc is not clear to me.

Comment: Using Spring, there is a very natural way to do this.  If not, the 'spring' way would be to scan the classpath for classes that implement IFoo, instantiate them as singletons (reflection), and allow you to invoke the method in IFoo for each occurrence found.  If you ever added a new Foo4 one day, your framework automatically detects it and uses it.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, `baz` needs all of them. basically `baz` is a `Runnable` and for every `run()` it calls this method of every `IFoo` class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one the dependency injection frameworks: it will permit to you to have singletons for the instance of `IFoo`.

You can also do something like

```
FooPool {

    private List<IFoo> foos;

    FooPool () {
        foos.add(Foo1.getInstance());
        foos.add(Foo2.getInstance());
        foos.add(Foo3.getInstance());
    }

    public List<IFoo> getFoos() {
        return foos
    }
}
```

`IFoo` Implementation would be singletons. You can make `FoolPool` also as a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved applying the Factory pattern.

Replace your singleton by a FooFactory class that can either be a Bean or static. The method getFoo(?) will contain the logic to return the right object.

---

EDIT: added another suggestion according to your comment.

Create a listener where all IFoo implementations will be registered upon instantiation. When it's time, Baz will run through the list and call the method of every IFoo registered in the listener.

Comment: but then again, I'll need to do something like: `FooFactory.create("foo1")`

Comment: Or to use an `Enum` instead of a `String`. Anyhow, someone need to iterate this enum/list of strings.

Comment: What's the logic to select among all Foos?

Comment: `Baz` need to call every `IFoo` class

Comment: I added another suggestion in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

> for every run() it calls this method of every IFoo class

I use `enum` for strategy classes, where there is one instance per strategy

```
interface IFoo {
    void doSomething();
}

enum Foos implements IFoo {
  FOO1 {
     public void doSomething() {

     }
  },
  FOO2 {
     public void doSomething() {

     }
  },
  FOO3 {
     public void doSomething() {

     }
  }
```

}

To call doSomething on all instances

```
for (IFoo foo : Foos.values()) {
   foo.doSomething();
}
```

Here is an example where I have used this.

https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire/blob/master/src/main/java/net/openhft/chronicle/wire/WireType.java

Comment: Very neat! I didn't know something like that can be done

Comment: @Elimination I use values in a loop when I want to test all possible implementations in a unit test,

Comment: @Elimination You can't sub-class an enum but you can have more than one enum implement the same interface and have a collection of these implementations.